# Using AWS Boto3 Invoke API Gateway from EC2 Instance

Tags: python-requests, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I am trying to invoke AWS API Gateway endpoint from one of the EC2 instance with IAM Role. I have boto3 library installed on EC2 instance and trying to execute simple gateway API using below code but still getting Authentication missing error.

```
import boto3
import json
import requests
from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth

session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()

headers = {'params': 'ABC'}
response = requests.get('https://restapiid.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stage/resource_path',
                        auth=credentials, headers=headers)
```

This should be very simple from EC2 Instance with IAM Role. Please any advise.

Comment: Can you replace  session.get_credentials() with session.get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials() and try again? If it still doesn't work update your question with error details

Answer (score 7):

Due to lack of details in your question, (missing instance role details, API gateway policy, unknown `headers`, or wheather `iam_auth` is enabled) I can only provide and comment on the python code given.

The python code to use role should be (this is example that I used to **verify** the code):

```
import boto3
import requests
from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth

session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()

auth = AWSRequestsAuth(aws_access_key=credentials.access_key,
                       aws_secret_access_key=credentials.secret_key,
                       aws_token=credentials.token,
                       aws_host='fzoskzctgd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
                       aws_region='us-east-1',
                       aws_service='execute-api')


response = requests.get('https://fzoskzctgd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test', auth=auth)

print(response.content)
```

I tested this with `authorizationType` set to `AWS_IAM` for the resource a tested.

**API resource policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456:role/instance-role"
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:170576413884:fzoskzctgd/test/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**instance-role**

Does not need to have any api invocation permissions as they are provided through API resource policy. The instance-role must only exist and be attached to the instance.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if your boto3 session is assuming role to a different AWS account. still trying to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Use the session from the assumed role. Or did you mean something else ?